# How to set desktop wallpaper and screen-saver?

Tags: cocoa, macos, screensaver, wallpaper

How to set desktop wallpaper and screen-saver from cocoa app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're on Mac OS X 10.6, [NSWorkspace](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/index.html) has some new methods for setting the desktop picture. The one you want is [setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/setDesktopImageURL:forScreen:options:error:).

As for screen saver, there's no supported way to do this programatically. You could modify the com.apple.screensaver plist file and set the following keys:

- moduleName <-- screen saver name
- idleTime <-- interval in seconds
- modulePath <-- path to screen saver file

However, this could break at any time so I would not rely on it.

Comment: I need setting wallpaper on previous MacOSX too

Comment: You could use something like NSAppleScript and then use AppleScript to change the wallpaper: http://still-scripts.com/applescript/change-your-desktop-background-with-applescript/

Comment: Note that on Lion this will only set the wallpaper of the currently active space, not of all spaces. Currently the only workaround seems to be to go back to pre 10.6 hacks

Comment: It seems that we can't set the wallpaper as tiled using the NSWorkspace method. Any ideas?